# Why running flask app.run with gunicorn and uwsgi is problematic?

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-compose, gunicorn

There is an idea that indicates not to run flask app in production with gunicorn or uwsgi. Tiangolo has mentioned in one of his repositories that app.run should be used just for development, not deployment or production. [Link to Tiangolo's comment on this topic](https://github.com/tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask-docker/blob/master/example-flask-package-python3.8/app/app/main.py#L9)
His code is as follows:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

from .core import app_setup


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Only for debugging while developing
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True, port=80)
```

My Question is why running flask app can be problematic(the last line of the aforementioned code) and should be removed or commented out. I carried out a series of tests and found out that with or with running flask app at production the number of generated processes are the same. Here are the outputs of my tests with gunicorn.

Here is my docker-compose. At line 12 you can check how I run gunicorn.

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  face:
    build: ./app
    container_name: face
    restart: always
    expose:
      - 660
    environment:
      - ENDPOINT=/face
      - FACE_DETECTION_MODEL=MTCNNTorchFaceDetector
    command: gunicorn --workers=2 --threads 1 -b 0.0.0.0:660 entry_point:app --worker-class sync

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    container_name: nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    depends_on:
      - face
```

flask gunicorn 2 processes with app.run:

```
root@e6c7d9ef03cc:/app# cat entry_point.py 
from endpoints import FaceDetection
from base_app import app, api, ENDPOINT

api.add_resource(FaceDetection, ENDPOINT)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run("127.0.0.1", port=3000)
root@e6c7d9ef03cc:/app# lsof -i
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
gunicorn   1 root    5u  IPv4 471109      0t0  TCP *:660 (LISTEN)
gunicorn   7 root    5u  IPv4 471109      0t0  TCP *:660 (LISTEN)
gunicorn   8 root    5u  IPv4 471109      0t0  TCP *:660 (LISTEN)
root@e6c7d9ef03cc:/app#
```

As you can see in the code, there are 3 processors which one of them is the master and the other two are the workers.

flask gunicorn 2 processes without app.run(it's commented out):

```
root@e6c7d9ef03cc:/app# cat entry_point.py 
from endpoints import FaceDetection
from base_app import app, api, ENDPOINT

api.add_resource(FaceDetection, ENDPOINT)

# if __name__ == '__main__':
#     app.run("127.0.0.1", port=3000)
root@e6c7d9ef03cc:/app# lsof -i
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
gunicorn   1 root    5u  IPv4 466580      0t0  TCP *:660 (LISTEN)
gunicorn   8 root    5u  IPv4 466580      0t0  TCP *:660 (LISTEN)
gunicorn   9 root    5u  IPv4 466580      0t0  TCP *:660 (LISTEN)
root@e6c7d9ef03cc:/app#
```

The outputs are the same and discarding the master processor there are only 2 main workers up and running.
 The same happens for gunicorn applications with 4 processors.
With app.run:

```
root@f1d9f2d3a5d0:/app# cat entry_point.py 
from endpoints import FaceDetection
from base_app import app, api, ENDPOINT

api.add_resource(FaceDetection, ENDPOINT)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run("127.0.0.1", port=3000)
root@f1d9f2d3a5d0:/app# lsof -i
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
gunicorn   1 root    5u  IPv4 484435      0t0  TCP *:660 (LISTEN)
gunicorn   7 root    5u  IPv4 484435      0t0  TCP *:660 (LISTEN)
gunicorn   8 root    5u  IPv4 484435      0t0  TCP *:660 (LISTEN)
gunicorn   9 root    5u  IPv4 484435      0t0  TCP *:660 (LISTEN)
gunicorn  10 root    5u  IPv4 484435      0t0  TCP *:660 (LISTEN)
root@f1d9f2d3a5d0:/app#
```

Without app.run:

```
root@f1d9f2d3a5d0:/app# cat entry_point.py 
from endpoints import FaceDetection
from base_app import app, api, ENDPOINT

api.add_resource(FaceDetection, ENDPOINT)

# if __name__ == '__main__':
#     app.run("127.0.0.1", port=3000)
root@f1d9f2d3a5d0:/app# lsof -i
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
gunicorn   1 root    5u  IPv4 476011      0t0  TCP *:660 (LISTEN)
gunicorn   8 root    5u  IPv4 476011      0t0  TCP *:660 (LISTEN)
gunicorn   9 root    5u  IPv4 476011      0t0  TCP *:660 (LISTEN)
gunicorn  10 root    5u  IPv4 476011      0t0  TCP *:660 (LISTEN)
gunicorn  11 root    5u  IPv4 476011      0t0  TCP *:660 (LISTEN)
root@f1d9f2d3a5d0:/app#
```

To reproduce the issue clone [face-detection-flask-gunicron-docker-compose](https://github.com/pooya-mohammadi/face-detection-flask-nginx-gunicorn-docker) and run the following commands:

```
# get the project
git clone https://github.com/pooya-mohammadi/face-detection-flask-nginx-gunicorn-docker.git
# cd to project's root 
cd ace-detection-flask-nginx-gunicorn-docker
# build the images and run the project
sudo docker-compose up --build
# open a new terminal
sudo docker ps -a 
# get the container-id for face-detection_face
# open a bash command with that container-id
sudo docker exec -it <container-i> bash # This opens a new command line
# install lsof to view listening services
apt-get install lsof
# view app.run condition
cat entry_point.py | grep app.run # The default is not commented. 
lsof -i
```

Comment the app.run in the entry_point.py and run the process again. 
To change the number of workers, modify line 12 in docker-compose.yml.

Comment: Please edit the question to make it clearer what you're asking.  I gather you have a Flask application, in a GitHub repository, that produces some PNG files?  You should include the details of the issue in text in the question directly (not as images and not behind links), and you need to include a [mcve] directly in the question as well (not just a link to your repository).

Comment: @DavidMaze
Thanks for your reply. I removed the images. Still, for reproducing the issue, one needs to run docker-compose.

Comment: You also need to include the `docker-compose.yml` file in the question if it's part of the MRE.  I'm a little unclear as to why you're doing so much in a shell alongside your container process; do you have the same issue running the same code outside Docker in an ordinary Python virtual environment?

Comment: @DavidMaze
Actually, it's not an issue. I believe it's a misunderstanding. I had doubts about why people keep saying that you shouldn't keep the app.run in your entrypoint.py. I carried out several tests to show that keeping the app.run in the entry_point does not make any difference to the number of generated processors. In the first answer, I illustrated that the app.run is under __main__ and it won't be executed by Gunicorn and it's pretty safe to keep it there.

Comment: Do you mean a Docker entrypoint (Dockerfile `ENTRYPOINT` directive, Compose `entrypoint:` override) or a Python setuptools `entry_points` script wrapper?  (I think this is one source of my confusion: I see `entry_point.py` and assume it's the main container process.)

Comment: @DavidMaze
No, I don't mean docker `ENTRYPOINT.` The `entry_point.py` is the module where the gunicorn Gets the flask app instance and executes[`gunicorn entry_point:app` ...] it. There is a misunderstanding that says if you put `app.run()` inside the `entry_point.py`(the name can be different for different projects) it will cause another unwanted process to be generated while running gunicorn. But as I explain in the answer section it's but a misunderstanding and as long as the `app.run()` is located inside `if __name__ == "__main__"` It won't be executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After digging around with gunicorn library for a while, I noticed that gunicorn uses `import.import_module` to import the entrypoint module(The module that contains the app, in my case entry_point.py) and the codes under `if __name__ == '__main__':` won't be executed and it's pretty safe to put anything there. [Link to import_app method in gunicorn library](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/76f8da24cbb992d168e01bda811452bcf3b8f5b3/gunicorn/util.py#L351). This method is called from method `load_wsgiapp` [link to load_wsgiapp](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/76f8da24cbb992d168e01bda811452bcf3b8f5b3/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py#L47) inside the primary runner class `WSGIApplication` [Link to WSGIApplication class](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/76f8da24cbb992d168e01bda811452bcf3b8f5b3/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py#L13).
As I noticed Tiangolo meant that using flask app directly for production is not safe because:

> The flask application server  is not developed or tested for production performance or security.

[Answer from Justin Triplett(discord)](https://discord.com/channels/531221516914917387/531571912619458591/928257821475221526)